# How can one test if a property was set to DateTime.Now

Tags: .net, unit-testing, datetime, nunit

I'm using NUnit to unittest a project. I have some code that creates an object and uses datetime.now to register the moment the object was created. This data can be very important, so it must be unittested to assure it works correctly.

When verifying the properties of the object, the current datetime is no longer the same as it was when the entity was created. How can I test it was set correctly? I am thinking of testing if the difference between the property's value and the current datetime is small enough, but this might be invalid on slower machines.

I cannot pass a variable along to the method that creates the object, so I cannot compare the set value to a value that is known.

Comment: You need to mock the clock. .NET 8 added the [ITimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.itimer?view=net-8.0) and [TimeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeprovider?view=net-8.0) types to allow unit tests to control what `Now` returns. In previous versions you can use the [Microsoft.Bcl.TimeProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.TimeProvider) package. Check [Avoiding flaky tests with TimeProvider and ITimer](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-avoiding-flaky-tests-with-timeprovider-and-itimer/)

Comment: Side suggestion, don't use DateTIme.Now, use DateTime.UtcNow. Now will use the timezone that your system is in which can get confusing and cause issues if people not in your timezone will be accessing the date. General rule of thumb is to store dates in Utc time and only convert when displaying to a user.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will try that!

Comment: @ZackR How can one then retrieve the value in the correct timezone when it was stored in utc now?

Comment: @ZackR that's not a rule of thumb at all, nor does it protect from problems. It's a common fallacy that the application only uses one timezone, and if it uses more, you'll know which the correct one was *after* you remove that information by storing UTC. Just one client from *another* timezone will be enough to start causing problems.

Comment: @Zenith they can't, because they no longer know what that timezone was. They only know which is the server's or current client's timezone or offset. That's why TimeProvider returns a DateTimeOffset, not DateTime. The offset isn't enough to identify the timezone, but it's better than nothing at all. Libraries like NodaTime use the IANA timezone names to explicitly specify the timezone, eg `Europe/Berlin`, or `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the in depth explanation. If I understand correctly, (there's quite some info here ;)) then you are saying that using DateTime would result in a difference in response when a user from a different timezone requests the same information. IE: user Asia gets a different webapi response than user Europe while requesting the same data. 

Isn't that preferable because it matches their sense of time in that the creation might have happened one hour ago so the difference between their current time and the time in response differ one hour? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would like a bit more of an explanation as well please. I have not seen a code base where the internal storage of time wasn't done as UTC time. The process that I have seen is either the API produces/accepts only UTC time and it is a UI's responsibility to convert that time to the current time zone of the user, or a user would have a time zone associated with their account stored in a DB and the API would accept and produce time in that time zone but convert it to UTC for consistent storage.

Comment: @ZackR the only thing that proves is a limited code base exposure. Timezone rules change. If you don't even know the offset, you can't handle that change. Whether you agree or not, TimeProvider returns a DateTimeOffset. If you *don't save the offset, you're losing information. The offset isn't enough information either, which is why applications use the IANA timezone names like `Europe/Berlin`

Comment: For a good explanation check Jon Skeet's [Storing UTC is not a Silver Bullet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/). Jon Skeet wrote the NotaTime library which is used by all software that actually cares about timezones.

Comment: And as for real examples that affected millions: Russia changed its timezone rules 2-3 times in 5 years. Egypt declared a DST rule change with only a few weeks notice. If airlines and travel agencies only stored UTC, we'd never be able to handle these changes and *you* would arrive at the wrong time for your flight.

Comment: That doesn't happen because we store *more* than just the UTC time. At the very least the airport along with its offset *and* IANA timezone name is stored. UTC is only needed as a convenience column if the database doesn't have a `datetimeoffset` type.

Comment: So I read though that post and I will admit that it discusses circumstances that I haven't had issues with. When I have dealt with future dates the circumstances were a little different since I worked with commercial shipping vessels that were constantly crossing time zones so we used AIS data to determine UTC offset. So I guess at this point the question for @Zenith is what the date is being used for. Since he is recording the time the object is being created then it matters why that time is relevant. Is it being used for accurate meta data, or will it be exposed to a user.

Comment: Oh and @Zenith if this is for work you should check with your team/company as they might already have a policy in place. Keeping your team happy is sometimes more important than being "right" :P

Comment: Interesting discussion and article! The use for the datetime is merely to provide an audittrail. Since our software has a regional appliance, we don't need to account for changes in timezones. What I can distill from this convo is that the use of DateTime.Now is inadviseable and DateTime.UtcNow is always preferable, though not prefect. I hope one of you puts this into an answer to the question and suggests the use of either DateTime.UtcNow or the TimeProvider, with of course the references that support this suggestion. From your comments I'm not sure how I can change and/or test my use case.